# One step checkout automatically comes back to free shipping when I select payment method

Tags: cart, shipping, payment-methods, shipping-methods, onestepcheckout

I'm using a template delivered with One Step Checkout.

I set up 2 different shipping options:
- free shipping 
- express shipping

By default Free shipping is always selected. I have no problem with that.

But when a customer clicks to select the payment method (paypal), then the cart reloads and the shipping becomes free shipping, even if express shipping was selected before.

How can I prevent such behavior?

You can have a look at [www.tendance24.fr](http://www.tendance24.fr) if you want to test the bug.

To reproduce on the order page select a paying shipping method, it reloads the cart calculation (Ajax update), then select the payment method, let it load, you'll see in the price description that the free shipping has overtaken the paying one we selected earlier.

Comment: I tested and I can't reproduce that bug.

Comment: I've edited to indicate step by step how to reproduce the issue

Comment: It didn't reload when i choose something...

Comment: It's reloading only the cart, it's an Ajax reloading not a whole page reloading

Comment: Ok, i saw it...

Comment: It happens to me as well so I/customers must select it again. I found a bigger problem with the OSC. If you guys would check it on your systems and share if it is a common problem or it is the problem on my OneStepCheckout only. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198767/magento-checkout-issue