# Magento checkout issue - SOLVED - i hope

Tags: magento-1.9, onestepcheckout

I just found a weird thing in checkout (Magento 1.9.2.3)
If customer have two pages opened, one is a checkout page and another one is a product page and customer will proceed with checkout but in the meantime go back to the product page it can affect  order content if customer add another item to the basket but in checkout this change will not be applied (but order in will) so after the payment is done customer will pay for example only for one item while on order there will be more.There should be a order validation before the form is submitted to the payment gateway.
Did anyone met this or similar problem before ?

Update:

In the meantime We've checked it on other Magento installations and it seems like a serious issue. Of course if the shop owner is not checking all of the orders and it's content and prices.
We tested it on three different Magento instances and everyone was doing the same, once you fill up the form and select delivery and payment method go to the second page where you can select and add another item to the basket, then go back to the checkout and click "Place the order"
then add another item quickly to the basket. Magento will save order with new content but payment will be recorded with only one.

Coincidence ???
Or is this the problem with Magento 1.9.2.3 ??

Comment: more info with pics need.

Comment: need some time to prepare (don't want there any details so somebody can exploit my shop :))

Comment: yaa i understand that. Is this happen only with extrenal payment method only? like paypa etc.. or with COD also?

Comment: Not using COD, paypal and sagepay only. But it does not matter what payment method. Once you fill up the form, select payment and shipping, then open separate page and add something to the basket checkout is not verifying basket content while submitting form. That's why customer pay only for one item but in backend order contains other items as well.

Comment: it seems like it is not a problem with OSC, it's a Magento issue and payment gateway.

Comment: Are you using ebizmarts sagepay? It has a 'validate quote' option in admin

Comment: Yes Ricky, ebizmarts sagepay module 3.4.6 or something :) and is deffinitely set to "yes" :P

Comment: I think I found it, it's not 'validate quote but 'verify cart consistency during transaction' :P i hope this will work. So guys please check your settings just in case  :) also there is an option 'Check if amounts match' this will also check if everything is ok then save order in Magento.

Comment: @RobertA. Please add your answer(comment) as an answer , so other also get benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Guys sorry for the alarm but it was something what I never expected. Apparently my predecessors who configured everything missed some settings in `SagePay`.

So to make sure everything will work properly and there will be no possibility to update order right before or after payment is processed check in `SagePay` settings this two options:

1. 'validate quote',
2. 'Check if amounts match'.

This options **"on"** should help a lot and check if there was anything changed in order content before processing payment regardless on how many tabs/pages customer was buying items.